# Copy large files in fastest way possible in Android

Tags: java, android

I need to copy files from one destination to another in Android. For that I'm using FileStreams method to copy files. It works fine. But when it's copying large file (more than 400M) , it takes a lot of time. I have found several other methods, but those were not working with Android.

Are there any specific methods in Android to do this better?

```
      InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceLoc);

      OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetLoc);

      byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
      int len;
      while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
      out.write(buf, 0, len);
```

Comment: Have you read about data chunkings and gzip? These would make your downloading effecient

Comment: the code you posted is perfectly ok

Comment: @ falsify - ok I'll check. This is not regarding downloading.

@pskink- yes, but it takes time with large files.

Comment: Do you need to specifically copy it or could you just move it?

Comment: then use `BufferedInputStream` / `BufferedOutputStream`

Comment: `the code you posted is perfectly ok`. It could benefit from a larger buffer though. @pskink.

Answer (score 0):

if both files are on the device, you could exec a cp command and see if that is faster.